# What might one want to accomplish by running ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -map 0 -map_metadata 0:s:0 -c copy video.mp4 in terms of forensics?

Tags: forensics, video

In the eighth episode of the second series of [Mr. Robot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mr._Robot), Trenton
does this to the video that was recorded by a VHS camera before releasing it to the public via [Vimeo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vimeo).

`ffmpeg -i fuxFBI.mp4 -map 0 -map_metadata 0:s:0 -c copy fuxFBI.mp4`

From what I gathered from `man ffmpeg`, the command copies the metadata from the first stream of the input file,
most likely a video stream, to the global metadata of the output file.
One noticeable effect of this command is that it stripped the output file of `handler_name   : SoundHandler` and the
`major_brand` tag. From the operational / forensic point of view, what advantage does the execution of this command give to her and to her crew of hackers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From the operational / forensic point of view, what advantage does the execution of this command give to her and to her crew of hackers?

Nothing. At least they ran an actual [UNIX] command vs. many movies which continue to show made up UI full of gibberish. Normal forensics tries not to modify the source data as possible (researches usually use byte-perfect imaging to work with data) as any modifications may lead to various clues getting lost.

My personal favorite is the Matrix Reloaded movie `nmap`/`sshnuke` were [used](https://nmap.org/movies/) - that was as close to reality as possible.